Was this ever a song by the Byrds?
So here it is, 1970, and I get a new album by The Byrds called "The Ballad of Easy Rider." One of the songs on the album was "The Green Hills of Earth." I got excited because I remembered the Robert Heinlein short story of the same name. When I listened to the song the lyrics were unmistakably about the same situation as the Heinlein story.
I remember the tune and some of the lyrics. Part of the refrain goes:

Let me rest my eyes
On fleecy skies
And the cool green hills of Earth

At some point I lost the album and when I went to buy a newer version on CD there was no "Green Hills of Earth" on it. I searched and searched, but for 20 or 30 years it was as if the song had never existed.
Now, I'm relatively sure I'm not crazy and didn't dream this song, nothing like that. Does anybody else remember this song? Can someone tell me how and why this song disappeared?

In 1970 Southwind released a 7" with the track "Cool Green Hills of Earth" in which those lyrics appear. Could it be that song?

This is the song I remember, definitely, but not by The Byrds, and 1970 is the exact period of time. Thank you. I wonder why it was removed from the "Ballad of Easy Rider" album. Though I've never even heard of the band Southwind, I'm pretty sure they must have traveled in the same circles as Roger McGuinn, who put out "Ballad" as a solo album, though under the Byrds name.

Searching further, looks like Southwind's released an album "Ready to Ride". Similar name, same year?
